# Skimmers and bank accounts and banking security

Tags: banking, online-banking, security

I have read that banks will reimburse for "fraudulent activities". If I have a savings account and checking account, and my ATM is not linked to say my checking account, can this account ever be skimmed? e.g. Only keep a small amount in account that is available at an ATM to reduce inconveniences while getting reimbursed?

Second question, are there best practices that security "experts" recommend regarding online banking, ATM banking, etc.

Examples:

- Online Password: afaik - at a minimum 8 characters, Mixed case, Alpha and numeric, At least one symbol
- Security Questions: afaik - Treat as online password
- Receipts: afaik - Never leave receipts from ATM at bank
- ATM Pin: afaik - Usually limited by banking institute.

e.g. Convenience over security.

Comment: Does "Online Password: afaik - 8 characters" mean **only** 8 characters to you?  Because, all else being equal, longer passwords are more secure than short ones -- and that means 16 is more secure than 8.

Comment: If an account is not linked to an ATM card, you can't use an ATM-based attack to steal from it. The rest of your question is really broad and hard to answer within the context of Stack Exchange. It might be better for you to do some research on general best practices and then consider asking any *specific* single question(s) you have afterwards.

Comment: There are two very different questions here. It might be a good idea to move one of them to it's own question.

Comment: Make use of the "alerts" that the bank offers. My bank sends me an email when my card is used at a gas station (high fraud rate location). I setup a low-balance alert email, so I know when my balance drops below a predetermined level. Fraud is easier to fix when it is caught quickly.

Comment: Note that there is an emerging technology for authenticating with an ATM using your phone instead of a card and PIN.  While chip-based (EMV) transactions can't be reproduced by a skimmer, you still had to stick your card, chip AND magstripe, into a slot, and the skimmer can steal the magstripe information and perform non-EMV transactions with it.  Use a phone instead of the card's chip, together with the exact same EMV algorithm, and now there is no easily-readable magnetic stripe anywhere in proximity.

Answer (score 1):

**Ask directly to your bank**

The best source of information would be your own bank. 
Every institution has his own policies regarding online banking and password managment for the different channels in which their products are delivered to their customers.

Take in account that reimburse  for "fraudulent activities" would take time, since the bank would need to investigate if you are not trying to scam them.